# PWA and service-worker

Tags: service-worker

Recently created a PWA with service-worker and everything runs great on local testing server, the resources and cache gets updated on each version change of the service-worker.

I am getting a problem though with a live IIS Win server, where it seems its serving server cache above the service-worker cache, or perhaps a cached version of the service-worker. Has anyone ran into this problem with an IIS Win Server? The PWA is html and js based.

Comment: Based on these details it's impossible to answer. Inspect the server's responses with Devtools and see how deployments get handled. It's not magic. Also, remember to set no-cache headers to sw.js!

Answer (score 0):

It was on the IIS server side, what I did was set a max-age to 60 header, and also disabled the CACHE on this particular site. This meant that the service-worker took over cache control, and I could see it updating as I change version number. So in other words IIS was caching the service-worker file.